# How to set up output path while copying data from Azure Cosmos DB to ADLS Gen 2 via Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a cosmos DB collection in the following format:

```
{
    "deviceid": "xxx",
    "partitionKey": "key1",
    .....
    "_ts": 1544583745
}
```

I'm using Azure Data Factory to copy data from Cosmos DB to ADLS Gen 2. If I copy using a copy activity, it is quite straightforward.  However, my main concern is the output path in ADLS Gen 2.  Our requirements state that we need to have the output path in a specific format.  Here is a sample of the requirement:

```
outerfolder/version/code/deviceid/year/month/day
```

Now since deviceid, year, month, day are all in the payload itself I can't find a way to use them except create a lookup activity and use the output of the lookup activity in the copy activity.

[image]

And this is how I set the ouput folder using the dataset property:

[image]

I'm using SQL API on Cosmos DB to query the data.

Is there a better way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your way works, but its not the cleanest. What I'd do is create a different variable inside the pipeline for each one: version, code, deviceid, etc. Then, after the lookup you can assign the variables, and finally do the copy activity referencing the pipeline variables.

[image: Proposed pipeline]

It may look kind of redundant, but think of someone (or you 2 years from now) having to modify the pipeline and if you are not around (or have forgotten), this way makes it clear how it works, and what you should modify.

Hope this helped!!

Comment: Thanks for this.  But whenever I use the set variable activity under names under variables there is nothing in the dropdown.  How can I set that?

Comment: You have to create the variables in the pipeline before using the set variable. Just click outside of any activity, and create the variables in the pipeline.

Comment: I also wanted to ask whether there is way to avoid using the lookup activity and get the variables from the copy activity itself.  The source query is using SQL API and has the data.  Can I somehow use that directly?

Comment: I dont think you can avoid the lookup :( maybe with something external and passing parameters to the pipeline, but you would be hitting the API nevertheless.